# WCF ERROR- (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: web-services, web, http-status-code-413

I have 2 WCF service working together. One is Class Library and another one in webservice.

Its working fine until now. But if i try to send large amount of data it throw me 413 error...

***`An exception was thrown: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.`***

Below is web.config file-

**For Class Library-**

> ```
>     <add key="SMTP" value ="dummy"/>
>     <add key="BookingEmailFrom" value ="dummy"/>
>     <add key="BookingEmailToWBD" value ="dummy"/>
>
>   </appSettings>
>   <connectionStrings/>
>   <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
>     <!--
>         The <authentication> section enables configuration 
>         of the security authentication mode used by 
>         ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
>     -->
>     <authentication mode="Windows"/>
>     <!--
>         The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
>         of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
>         during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
>         it enables developers to configure html error pages 
>         to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
>          <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
>          <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
>         </customErrors>
>     -->
>     <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
>   </system.web>
>   <!-- 
>       The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
>       Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
>   -->
>   <system.serviceModel>
>     <services>
>       <service name="JSONWebService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="JSONWebService.Service1Behavior">
>         <endpoint address="../Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONWebService.IService1"
> ```
>
> behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
>
> For web service client-
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <configuration>
>   <!-- 
>       Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
>       web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
>       the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
>       A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
>       machine.config.comments usually located in 
>       \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
>   -->
>   <configSections>
>
>   </configSections>
>   <appSettings>
>     <add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=dummy;uid=sa;pwd=dummy;database=dummy"/>
> ```
>
> ---------------------- -->
>         
>         
>         
>           
>           
>             
>               
>               
>               
>               
>               
>             
>           
>            section enables configuration 
>               of the security authentication mode used by 
>               ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
>           -->
>           
>            section enables configuration 
>               of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
>               during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
>               it enables developers to configure html error pages 
>               to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
>
> ```
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
>          <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
>          <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
>         </customErrors>
>     -->
>     <pages>
>       <controls>
>         <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> ```
>
> PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
>
> ```
>           <!-- 
>               Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
>               identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
>               automatically.
>           -->
>           <identity>
>             <dns value="localhost"/>
>           </identity>
>         </endpoint>
>         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
>         <endpoint address="basic" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONWebService.IService1"
> ```
>
> behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
>
> ```
>       </service>
>     </services>
>     <behaviors>
>       <serviceBehaviors>
>         <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
>           <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before
> ```
>
> deployment -->
>
> ```
>     </bindings>
>
>
>   </system.serviceModel>
>
>
>
> </configuration>
> ```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this? I have tried every soolution I could find online and nothing is working ...

Answer (score 5):

You are encountering a WCF default limit on the message size.  To raise the limit, use the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute in your web.config file (server side).

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You mean in Class Library?

Comment: Yes, I mean in the web.config for your server side web service.  So yes, your Class Library.  In that web.config there is already a system.serviceModel section defined, just add this to it.  Hope that works.

Comment: Hi i have added the <bindings> under <system.serviceModel> but it did not resolved my issue. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Also i ahev found another things, when i publish the service in my local dev machine it gives 413 but when published in our web server it throw error (400) Bad request.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably really late, but for anyone else that is also stuck.

The initial problem is solved by what BilalAlam described (increase the maxRecievedMessageSize) but your issue is the bindings need to be tied to the endpoint via the *bindingConfiguration* in the endpoint and the *name* in the binding.

Example

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" name="NAMETOTIEENDPOINT">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service>
    <endpoint address="basic" bindingConfiguration="NAMETOTIEENDPOINT" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONWebService.IService1"  />
  </service>
</services>
```